# Eigenvalues of a $d\times d$ diagonal+rank1 matrix in $O(d)$ time?

Tags: linear-algebra

Suppose $h$ is a vector of $d$ positive numbers adding up to 1. I'm looking for a $O(d)$ algorithm to estimate eigenvalues of the following diagonal + rank1 matrix:

$$A=2\operatorname{diag}(h)-hh^T$$

Empirically it [appears](https://www.wolframcloud.com/obj/yaroslavvb/nn-linear/forum-eigenvalues-over-2.nb) that $2h$ gives a good starting point for eigenvalues of $A$. How could I improve this estimate in $O(d)$ time?

[image]

Background: $f(t)=\operatorname{Tr} \exp(-t A)$ gives an estimate of mean error of SGD after $t/2$ steps of solving linear least squares for normally distributed data with covariance eigenvalues $h$ and a random starting distribution of error. Values of $h$ are [expected](https://www.wolframcloud.com/obj/yaroslavvb/nn-linear/forum-velikanov-berthier-example.nb) to decay at least as fast as power-law with constant >1

This follows from Equation 5 of Bordelon [paper](https://arxiv.org/abs/2106.02713) after discarding small terms, using approximation$(I-A)^t\approx e^{-t A} $ and this trace [result](https://stats.stackexchange.com/a/532222/511).

Equivalently, $f(t)$ gives expected value of $\|e\|^2$ after $t/2$ iterations of the form $e\leftarrow e-x\langle e, x\rangle$ for $x\sim \text{Normal}(0,\operatorname{diag}h)$ and isotropic starting $e_0$ with $\|e_0\|^2=1$.

[image]
[Notebook](https://www.wolframcloud.com/obj/yaroslavvb/nn-linear/mathoverflow-gaussian-convergence.nb)

Comment: See this: https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bunch%E2%80%93Nielsen%E2%80%93Sorensen_formula

Comment: You might also be interested in some references I gave (ten years ago) in answering this Math.SE [Question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/506761/maximum-eigenvalue-of-a-diagonal-plus-rank-one-matrix) about numerical eigenvalues of a diagonal-plus-rank-one matrix (a more general problem than the one you've asked about).  Readers will benefit from learning more about the context in which your version arose.

Comment: @hardmath added clarifications

Comment: Thanks, it helps to have an idea about the importance of approximating eigenvalues vs. exact values.  Also to think about how likely the components of $h$ are to be nearly equal.

Comment: @hardmath thanks. I've indeed found a couple of $O(d^2)$ methods, one of them lead to discussion and efficient [implementation](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/280401/efficient-eigendecomposition-of-dpr1-matrices/280669#280669). However, nothing I've seen suggests a way to approximate eigenvalues in $O(d)$ time

Comment: @hardmath more background on this problem is given [here](https://community.wolfram.com/groups/-/m/t/2902848)

Comment: @lightxbulb That formula is about computing the eigen*vectors* given the eigenv*values*.

Comment: @FedericoPoloni There is a paper from Golub in the references. It's $O(n^2)$ though and not $O(n)$. The characteristic polynomial has a pretty specific form in the above case, it's described in the paper.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I get a substantially better estimate if sort $h$ (descending) and estimate the eigenvalues as:

$$ \tilde\lambda_i = h_i + h_{i+1} $$

---

This works because a symmetric DPR1 matrix (with positive rank-one modification, no duplicate eigenvalues) has the *strict interlacing property*, which means that

$$ \lambda_1 > d_1 > \lambda_2 > d_2 > ... > \lambda_n > d_n $$

where $d_i$ are the entries of the diagonal matrix without the rank one modification. Details in [this paper](https://doi.org/10.1016/j.laa.2015.09.025), introduction up to equation 5. In your matrix structure, the rank one modification is negative, meaning

$$ A = D + \rho h h^T,\quad\rho < 0 $$

and thus the strict interlacing property applies to the negated matrix where the symmetric rank one modification is positive, like

$$ A = -D + \rho h h^T,\quad\rho > 0 $$

For your original matrix, that means

$$ d_i > \lambda_i > d_{i+1} $$

My estimator simply takes the average of the upper and lower bound. The image below shows the result for a random 15 element vector. Your estimator is equivalent to the upper bound shown here.

[image: Estimator performance comparison]

Comment: Interesting! The 2h estimator essentially approximates eigenvalues by diagonal values, and the error can be bounded by Gershgorin circle theorem. Not sure why $h_i+h_{i+1}$ works better

Comment: thanks for the update, this makes sense. Tried your [average](https://www.wolframcloud.com/obj/yaroslavvb/nn-linear/forum-dpr1-interlacing-marchenko.nb) formula on random matrices. Seems a lot better than upper/lower bound, although biased